# has_secure_password error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use bcryting, so I write:

User.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_sesure_password
end
```

Users Controller:

```
def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save?
      redirect_to "http://178.62.102.154:3000/"
    end
end

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password_digest)
end
```

And in load the page it prints:

`undefined local variable or method has_sesure_password' for User(id: integer, username: string, password_digest: string):Class`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think, it should be **has_secure_password**, not has_**sesure**_password

Comment: this, and make sure you have the ***bcrypt*** gem enabled in your Gemfile and have created the ***password_digest*** string column for your model.